# Can we use/simulate Solaris/Aix C/C++ compiler on windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, compilation, solaris

Is there any way of using aix/solaris compiler on windows so that we are sure the application would not break on non windows platform?
Different compilers expect the standards of code to be different ,Can this be made sure from one operating system?
I know that compiling on platforms like solaris/AIX would mean that the code would compile on windows compiler most of the times.
But can this process be done from windows , with the additional strictness required for non windows platforms?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? The question is tagged linux, so I'm wondering if you are using gcc

Comment: @Mansuro: I am using MS Visual Studio compiler on windows , on Linux I use gcc , even after successful compilation by these two compilers something breaks up on Solaris/AIX. Can this be detected on windows without having the need to compile on Solaris/AIX.

Comment: @k53sc Are you using Sun CC/XL on Solaris/AIX, or g++?  And what versions.  (And why on earth would one develop on Windows when one has Unix boxes at your disposition?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of.  Each compiler has its own idiosyncrasies, and it isn't reasonable to expect any one compiler to try to imitate all of the others.  What you should do (although as far as I know, g++ is the only compiler to offer the option) is to specify a fairly early version of the standard (e.g. `-std=c++98`), and hope for the best.  There will be special cases which it will miss (for a long time, Sun CC has non-conformant libraries, for example), but by not using C++11 features, for example, you should limit the problems.

If possible, the simplest solution might be to impose the same compiler (g++, or maybe clang) everywhere.

And of course, wrap anything that interfaces directly with the system.  (My experience is that programs which compile and run under Unix do *not* work under Windows, because there always seems to be the call to a Posix function in them, which isn't present under Windows, or has different semantics under Windows.  And back when I was doing most of this, my basic compiler was Sun CC, with the non-conformant library, which broke with VC++ and just about every other compiler as well.)

Comment: Thanks , I get that when compilation of unix code with POSIX would definitely break under windows, the platform dependent behavior doesn't break. What breaks and what caused me to post this question here is safe coding practices which are no so required for VS / gcc but should be followed for Solaris compilers. for example : the use of find() on std::maps in if statement breaks Solaris and passes for others. Similarly there are many issues like these , if these get detected by some compile setting in windows / Linux in form of warning , this may act as a alarm for a potential break.

Comment: @k53sc That sounds more like a bug in Sun CC than anything else.  In general, you cannot expect compiler writers to check for all cases where some compiler has a bug (although at least in the past, some compilers _have_ emulated bugs in VC++).

Comment: @k53sc FWIW: _if_ your code follows more or less reasonable coding standards, you might be able to write regular expressions which catch the problematic cases, and use them (in grep or python) to find them.  I did something like this a few years back when we encountered a case where VC++ wasn't calling destructors; I can't guarantee I found them all, but I did find three other cases in the code base which would trigger the error.  It's all very ad hoc, but it can save a lot of time, even if it isn't perfect.

Comment: Alright, I can have a script , which could check for all of these bugs(There are many like the one a gave as a example in previous comment , i was thinking of this as some kind on strictness follows by Solaris for safe practices etc. ) , I can check before compiling. Thanks for your help.